# How to make text processing operations on big corpus work (more efficiently)

Tags: python, nlp, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

How to get my Python script to work (efficiently) on a 33-million large set of documents?

Creating a Topic Model from [33-million PubMed abstracts](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/download/). At this point I have a binary pickle file that contains a Python list with the 33m abstracts (pubmed_abstracts.bin) as strings. I am trying to unpickle this list, tokenize the documents and then pickle the result, so I can use that in my next steps.

What I'd like to achieve is that I could tokenize these 33m documents with a 100% CPU-load (hence the chunking and asynchronous processing), while using less than 100% RAM and that it finishes without errors (these last two I cannot figure out yet). Feel free to download the [pubmed abstracts pickled 6k and 1m test sets](https://phitech.dev/pubmed_abstracts/pubmed_abstracts_test.zip). Full 33m corpus available upon request.

This script below works fine on smaller dataset (n=6k/6MB, or n=1m/600MB). But it doesn't work on the full n=33m/19GB dataset. In one case the script stopped because the memory ran out. In another case I'm getting "Process SpawnProcess-7:Process SpawnProcess-8:Process SpawnProcess-9:etc..". I'm working with i5/32GB, Win11, Anaconda, Python v3, Spyder v5.

```
## TOKENIZED CORPUS TO BINARY
## Spyder 5.1.5
## Python 3.9.7 64-bit


# %%
# Essentials
import pickle
import time
import concurrent.futures # Async script execution
import math

# Gensim
import gensim
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess


# %%
## Set environment
if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_test = False # Set to false to process full datasets (can take long)
    if is_test:
        file_location = 'C:/.../datasets_test/'; # Small dataset (n=5000) for demo
    else:
        file_location = 'C:/.../datasets_full/'; # Big dataset (n=33,000,000)
    
    
    # %%
    ## Retrieve binary file
    documents = pickle.load(open(file_location + "pubmed_abstracts.bin", 'rb'))
    #print(documents[55]) # Debugging
    
    
    # %%
    ## Separate full corpus into chunks
    big_chunks = []
    documents_per_big_chunk = 1000
    documents_per_small_chunk = 100
    number_of_big_chunks = math.ceil(len(documents) / documents_per_big_chunk) # Define enough chunks to contain entire corpus
    number_of_small_chunks = math.ceil(documents_per_big_chunk / documents_per_small_chunk) # Equally divide big chunk up into small chunks
    range_from = 0
    range_to = documents_per_small_chunk
    for _ in range(number_of_big_chunks):
        big_chunk = []
        for _ in range(number_of_small_chunks):
            if len(documents[range_from:range_to]) > 0:
                big_chunk.append(documents[range_from:range_to+1]) # If it isn't range_to+1, every 100th document is omitted. So range_to+1.
            print(f"range_from = {range_from}, range_to = {range_to}")
            range_from = range_to + 1
            range_to = range_to + documents_per_small_chunk
        big_chunks.append(big_chunk)
    del documents # Free up some much needed memory
    #print(len(big_chunks[0][0])) # Debugging
    #print(big_chunks[0][0][55]) # Debugging
    
    
    # %%
    ## 
    def tokenize_documents(documents):
        tokenized_documents = [gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(document, deacc=True) for document in documents]
        return tokenized_documents
    
    
    # %%
    ## Asynchronously tokenize documents
    ## https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso
    ## https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OKTAedgFYg
    tokenized_documents = []
    time_start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(len(big_chunks)):
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results = executor.map(tokenize_documents, big_chunks[i])
            for result in results:
                [tokenized_documents.append(document) for document in result]
    time_spent = str(round(time.perf_counter() - time_start, 2))
    print (f"time_spent = {time_spent}")
    
    # %%
    ## Pickle the resulting tokenized corpus
    pickle.dump(tokenized_documents, open(file_location + "pubmed_abstracts_tokenized.bin", 'wb'))
```

What I am looking for by posting this on SO is that someone may help me point at my mistakes and help me make a few steps in the right direction. I have made steps by myself like adding `if _name_ == '_main_':` and chunking my data and processing it asynchronously. I just figure that you, experienced folks on SO may help me save precious masters thesis time by taking a look at my code. What mistakes can you identify and what changes would you suggest?

Comment: Batch learning can help https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/Large_Scale_Machine_Learning_(Big_Data)

Comment: I have transformed the script now so that the bigger chunks are first pickled and written to a binary file, as a means of caching, so that it can later on load these cache files and process them synchronously (so then the RAM won't fill up). I'm in a world of errors now, and it is still not working.